# get the last element of a json file

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, web-services

**Edit 30/06/2020 with the working code. Thank you all!**

Hi i want to get the last element of a json file in my solution.
actually my webservice send all the json file :

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    

namespace getLastVersionNumber
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description résumée de WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // Pour autoriser l'appel de ce service Web depuis un script à l'aide d'ASP.NET AJAX, supprimez les marques de commentaire de la ligne suivante. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
       

        [WebMethod]

    public string IDVersion()
    {

        //JSON path
        String json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\sejjilali\source\repos\WebserviceProdware\getLastVersionNumber\idVersions.json");


        //Parsing, get last one and convert it to a string
        var lastVersion = JArray.Parse(json).Last().ToString();

        return lastVersion;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is a sample of my file:

[
{
"id": 1,
"version": 0.1
},
{
"id": 2,
"version": 0.5
},
{
"id": 3,
"version": 0.8
}
]

i just want to get the the last one **{ "id": 3, "version": 0.8 }**

thanx for help

Comment: `JArray.Parse(st).Last()`;

Comment: hi evan i tried it but it desn't work.  **JArray test = JArray.Parse(json).Last();**  last stays in red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to get the last element of json file.

```
        string path = "D:\\1.json";
        string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
        JToken test = JArray.Parse(text).Last();
        Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: HI Jack just edited the code withnthe solution. yours helped me thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First define class like this

```
public class Data{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public double version{get;set;}
}
```

After that you can just get the last value like this

```
List<Data> myDatas=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(stringfromwebservice);
Data myData=myDatas.Last();
```

Comment: thank you for your help sadullah, i'm reading your answer but how can i use it? do you have a topic i can read?

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
var stringfromwebservice="from web server data";
List<webservice>  webserviceList=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<webservice>>(stringfromwebservice);

webservice DataModel = webserviceList[webserviceList.Count];
```

Data model

```
public class webservice 
{
    int id { get; set; }
    double version { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please give some context information as well. Why do you think this piece of code should help the OP.